# Local formula for the signature of $4k$-manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff

In "[The Euler characteristic is the unique locally determined homotopy invariant of finite complexes](https://eudml.org/doc/131180)" on page 61 in the penultimate paragraph, Levitt mentions that if one restricts to compact PL $4k$-manifolds then the signature is "locally defined" - i.e. that there is a real-valued function $d$ on triangulated $(4k-1)$-spheres (up to simplicial-isomorphism) with the property that 
$$
\sigma(M) = \sum_{v \in M^0} d( \text{link}(v)).
$$

What is this function $d$?  I am particularly interested in the case where $k=1$.

Comment: Are you certain the claim about signature is made in that paper?  I'm scanning it over and I have not found the claim.  Could you give a page and line number?

Comment: @RyanBudney perhaps the OP was thinking of what's written on page 61 after Theorem B? http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN000365025&physid=PHYS_0065 . I'm not sure this is what is written in the question though.

Comment: As far as I know, such a formula has not been worked out.  It's one of those things that "in principle" exists but expressing $d$ explicitly as a function of triangulated spheres is likely a fair bit of work.  Perhaps someone working on invariants of triangulated manifolds might have some additional insights.